# Deleting multiple rows

Tags: php, mysql, datatables

I'm using datatables, and I have selected multiple rows and I want to perform delete operation on multiple rows. For example, I selected rows 2, 3, and 4, so I want all the 3 rows to be deleted at the same time.

```
<script>
var oTable;
var giRedraw = false;

$(document).ready(function() {
    /* Add a click handler to the rows - this could be used as a callback */
    $('#example tr').click( function() {
        if ( $(this).hasClass('row_selected') )
            $(this).removeClass('row_selected');
        else
            $(this).addClass('row_selected');
    } );


    /* Add a click handler for the delete row */
    $('#delete').click( function() {
        var anSelected = fnGetSelected( oTable );
        oTable.fnDeleteRow( anSelected[0] );
    } );

    /* Init the table */
    oTable = $('#example').dataTable( );
} );

function fnGetSelected( oTableLocal )
{
    var aReturn = new Array();
    var aTrs = oTableLocal.fnGetNodes();

    for ( var i=0 ; i<aTrs.length ; i++ )
    {
        if ( $(aTrs[i]).hasClass('row_selected') )
        {
            aReturn.push( aTrs[i] );
        }
    }
    return aReturn;
}

</script>
```

Through this script only 1 row gets deleted at a time.

Comment: Typing properly doesn't hurt either.

Comment: i am new to this site so ritenow can not accept any answer as reputation 15 is must. sorry for that

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
$('#delete').click( function() {
    var anSelected = fnGetSelected( oTable );
    oTable.fnDeleteRow( anSelected ); 
    // previously it was anSelected[0] which select only frist element
} );
```

**Edited**

I made some changes in the fnGetSelected() function. Might that help

```
function fnGetSelected( oTableLocal )
{
    var aReturn = new Array();
    var aTrs = oTableLocal.fnGetNodes();

    for ( var i=0 ; i<aTrs.length ; i++ )
    {
        // removed $() because this is already DOM element.
        if ( aTrs[i].hasClass('row_selected') ) 
        {
            aReturn.push( aTrs[i] );
        }
    }
    return aReturn;
}
```

Comment: no, this doesn't solves my purpose. even it starts deleting from row 1, whether selected or not.

Comment: if anSelected[0] deletes the first row and anSelected deletes everything, why not use a "for (var n=0; n<anSelected.length; n++) anSelected[n]" ?

Comment: anSelected[0] deletes the first selected row amongst multiple rows. anSelected deletes first row whether first row is selected or not. I want if i am selecting 2,5,8 then only 2,5,8 should get deleted and at the same time..